# mysql Insert query is not generated in excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to create insert query in excel

```
coll_1      coll_2     coll_3   
row1         row1      row1
row2         row2      row2
row3         row3      row3

="insert into customers ('" &A1&"','" & B1 & "','"&C1&"') values (" &A2&",'" & B2 & "','"&C2&"');"
```

this formula I have wrote, i want output as 
insert into customers ('coll_1','coll_2','coll_3') values (row1,'row1','row1');

column name should remain same after dragging the formula

```
insert into customers (coll_1,coll_2,coll_3) values (row1,'row1','row1');
insert into customers (coll_1,coll_2,coll_3) values (row2,'row2','row2');
insert into customers (coll_1,coll_2,coll_3) values (row3,'row3','row3');
```

I want my column name should remain same but values must be changed.

But I got wrong result

```
insert into customers (coll_1,coll_2,coll_3) values (row1,'row1','row1');
insert into customers (row1,'row1','row1') values (row2,'row2','row2');
insert into customers (row2,'row2','row2') values (row3,'row3','row3');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula looks close.  You only need to make some slight changes and also anchor the row in the columns portion of the insert, since you don't want that to change as you drag down your formula:

```
="INSERT INTO customers (" & A$1 & ", " & B$1 & ", " & C$1 &") VALUES ('" & A2 & "', '" & B2 & "', '" & C2 & "');"
```